# Error C2664 , need clarification

Tags: c++, c2664

I use this function in my programm and I call it by `receive(&head);`.I am doing something wrong and get an error c2664 : cannot convert parameter 1 from "link **" to "link *" when calling `QUEUEget(&head)`. If I understand it right `(*head)` is a link to another link so I should do something like `(&(&head))` but it doesn't work.

```
   void receive(link *head){
        int j;
        for (j=0;j<WINDOW;j++){
         if (((*head)->status==PENDING) || ((*head)->status==NEW)) {
             (*head)->status=ACK;
              printf("Packet No. %d: %d\n",(*head)->packetno,(*head)->status);
              QUEUEget(&head);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably in this context

```
QUEUEget(&head);
```

`head` is a `link*`. You are passing the address, which gives you a pointer to pointer, i.e. `link**`. You probably need

```
QUEUEget(head)
```

Comment: If I do that I should use `(head)->status` inside the `if` right?
Also if I use `receive(head);` I get the same problem but now when calling the function receive.

Comment: @user2192519 probably just `head->status`.

Comment: If I do that I get Error C2227: left of '->status' must point to class/struct/union/generic type.

Comment: @user2192519 well, that depends on what `link` is. Does it have a member called `status`?

Comment: Yes I have a struct with a member called status. Using `QUEUEget(head);` ,as others suggested, worked though.

Comment: @user2192519 that was what I suggested on the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> error c2664 : cannot convert parameter 1 from "link **" to "link *"
>   when calling QUEUEget(&head).

This is telling you that the `QUEUEget` function is expecting a `link*` (a pointer to a `link`) as its parameter, but you're passing it a `link**` (a pointer to a pointer to a `link`).

In your `receive` function, the parameter `head` is already a `link*`:

```
void receive(link *head);
```

However, in this line, you're passing the address of `head` (i.e. a pointer to a `link*`)to `QUEUEget`:

```
QUEUEget(&head);
```

Instead, just pass `head` directly:

```
QUEUEget(head);
```